# iOS PushKit registration not working on iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

I am implementing **[PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit)** for my VoIP application for iOS 10.

I have written this code in `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
private let _pushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)

//MARK: - App Life Cycle -
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //Register for local notifications
    NotificationController.registerNotifcationForApplication()
    
    //PushKit
    _pushRegistry.delegate = self
    var typeSet = Set<PKPushType>()
    typeSet.insert(.voIP)
    _pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = typeSet
    
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}

//MARK: - Delegates -
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials,  forType type: PKPushType) {
    DDLogVerbose("PushKit Token: \(credentials.token) length: \(credentials.token.count)")
    print("pushRegistry didUpdate credentials")
}

func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenForType type: PKPushType) {
    DDLogVerbose("")
    print("pushRegistry didInvalidatePushTokenForType")
}

func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {
    DDLogVerbose("Payload: \(payload.dictionaryPayload)")
    print("pushRegistry didReceiveIncomingPushWith")
}

}
```

I have enabled these background modes:
[image]

But **none of the delegate is getting called** when I launch the app.
It also not working on iOS 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it just simply by enabling `Push Notifications` in capabilities as:

[image]

Actually I tried this already also but it was not worked previously.
Now I enabled it, closed Xcode 8.2.1, reopen, clean-build and it worked!

Thanks for [this SO answer by vin25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864690/apple-pushkit-didupdatepushcredentials-is-never-called-on-ios-9?rq=1)

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal can you explain what all you did?

Comment: same thing done in objective-c. and i m getting token as well

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal This post was only about obtaining token, see edit. Better to start new post